# Dual atomic norm with respect to trigonometric polynomials basis set

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

The following is taken from chapter 9.2 from *Positive Trigonometric Polynomials and Signal Processing Applications* by Bogdan Dumitrescu.

Let $A$ be a symmetric set ($x \in A \implies -x \in A$) such that all *atoms* $a \in A$ are extreme points of $\text{conv}(A)$, i.e. $a \not\in \text{conv}(A \setminus \{ a \})$ for all $a \in A$.
The *atomic norm* associated with $A$ is
$$
\| x \|_A
:= \inf\{ t \ge 0: x \in t \cdot \text{conv}(A)\}.
$$
The dual atomic norm is
$$
\| h \|_A^*
\overset{\text{Def.}}{=} \sup_{\| x \|_A \le 1} \Re[x^{H} h]
= \sup_{a \in A} \Re[a^H h].
$$
Now consider 
$$
A
:= \{ a(w, \phi) := e^{i \phi} \psi(w): w, \phi \in [- \pi, \pi]\},
\quad \text{where } \psi(w) := [1, e^{i w}, \ldots, e^{i n w}].
$$
Up until here, everything is fine. 
But the author now claims
$$
\| h \|_{A}^*
= \sup_{w, \phi} \Re[h^{H} a(w, \phi)]
= \sup_{w, \phi}\left| e^{- i \phi} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w}\right|.
$$
I don't understand how the second equality is derived.
I get
\begin{align}
\Re[h^{H} a(w, \phi)]
& = \Re\left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \overline{h}_k e^{i \phi} e^{i k w} \right]
= \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \Re\left[\overline{h}_k e^{i \phi} e^{i k w} \right] \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \Re(h_k) \cos(\phi + w k) + \Im(h_k) \sin(\phi + w k)
\end{align}
using the formulae $\Re(a \cdot b) = \Re(a) \Re(b) - \Im(a) \Im(b)$ and $$\Re\left[e^{i \phi} e^{i k w}\right] = \Re\left[e^{i (\phi + k w)}\right] = \cos(\phi + k w).$$

Similarly, writing out the other side of the equality I get
\begin{align}
\left| e^{-i \phi} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w} \right|^2
& = \left| \sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w} \right|^2 
= \Re\left[\sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w}\right]^2 + \Im\left[\sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w}\right]^2 \\
& = \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \Re(h_k) \cos(w k) + \Im(h_k) \sin(w k) \right)^2 \\
& \qquad + \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \Im(h_k) \cos(w k) + \Re(h_k) \sin(w k) \right)^2,
\end{align}
which are both very different. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Re\left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \overline{h}_k e^{i \phi} e^{i k w} \right]=\Re\left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {h}_k e^{-i \phi} e^{-i k w} \right]$ using ($\Re z = \Re \bar z$)

$\Re\left[ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {h}_k e^{-i \phi} e^{-i k w} \right]=\Re (e^{-i\phi}S_n)$ where $S_n= \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {h}_k e^{-i k w}$

But now first $\Re (e^{-i\phi}S_n) \le |e^{-i\phi}S_n|=|S_n|$ so the supremum on the real part on $\phi,w$ is at most the supremum on the absolute value of the same and which depends only on $w$ (and on $n$ if that varies too, but not on $\phi$)

However for a fixed $w$ (and a fixed $n$ if needed) hence a fixed $S_n$ there is a (unique modulo $2\pi$ unless $S_n=0$) $\phi_{w,n}$ s.t $\Re (e^{-i\phi_{w,n}}S_n)=|S_n|$ so the supremum on the abolute values on $\phi,w$ is actually attained on the real part, so we get the required equality:

$\| h \|_{A}^*
= \sup_{w, \phi} \Re[h^{H} a(w, \phi)]
= \sup_{w, \phi}\left| e^{- i \phi} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k e^{- i k w}\right|.$